# Docker container has no internet: network host or ISP problem

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, dockerfile, host

I need help finding a way to access the internet in my docker container.

I changed ISP a few days ago and since then when I 'make up' the microservices of my project, no one container has access to the internet.

After many attempts, I tried this:

```
--net = host (in the docker run)
--network = host (when I build the image)
network_mode = "host" (in the docker-compose)
```

And finally I get access to the internet from the containers, but now I can't access to the urls of my services.

Any suggestions ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I contacted my ISP for connection problems with my docker containers, and they explained to me that they do not support them.
**Answer:** Change ISP.

Answer (score 0):

This is just fast fix on RHEL linux (not safest solution) for allowing container to access  external resources (outside docker infrastructure) setting up firwalld

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-service=http
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-service=https
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-interface=docker0
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-interface=docker_gwbridge
firewall-cmd --reload
```

For exposing application outside docker host (server running containers) you have to specify "expose ports" in your docker-compose.yml file

```
services:
  whoami-test:
    image: containous/whoami
    ports:
      # first is docker host listening port
      # second is docker container exposed port
      - 80:8080 
....
```

Or using command line command:

```
docker run --rm \
  -p 80:8080 \
  containous/whoami
```

Above strongly depends on your server/docker/container configuration so please **DO NOT** copy paste

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried your solution but dont work for me. Apparently my ISP is applying a double nat that does not allow me to get access to internet from my containers.